# Mapstruct: HashMap as source to Object

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

How could I use a `HashMap<String, Object>` as source to an object?

Here is my target object:

```
public class ComponentStyleDTO{
    private String attribute;
    private Object value;
}
```

I've tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226847/mapstruct-mapping-from-java-util-map-to-bean?answertab=votes#tab-top) approach that I found and that is also in the documentation, but it's failing for me.

My Mapper:

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, componentModel = "spring", uses = ComponentStyleMapperUtil.class)
public interface ComponentStyleMapper {

    ComponentStyleMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(ComponentStyleMapper.class);

    @Mappings({@Mapping(target = "attribute", qualifiedBy = ComponentStyleMapperUtil.Attribute.class),
    @Mapping(target = "value", qualifiedBy = ComponentStyleMapperUtil.Value.class)})
    ComponentStyleDTO hashMapToComponentStyleDTO(HashMap<String, Object> hashMap);
}
```

My Util:

```
public class ComponentStyleMapperUtil{
    @Qualifier
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface Attribute {
    }

    @Qualifier
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface Value {
    }


    @Attribute
    public String attribute(HashMap<String, Object> in){

        return (String) in.entrySet().stream().findFirst().get().getKey();
    }

    @Value
    public Object value(HashMap<String, Object> in) {
        Object value = in.entrySet().stream().findFirst().get().getValue();

        if(value instanceof String){
            return value;
        }else if(value instanceof LinkedHashMap){
            List<ComponentStyleDTO> childs = new ArrayList<ComponentStyleDTO>();
            HashMap<String, Object> child = (HashMap<String, Object>) value;
            for(String key: child.keySet()){
                ComponentStyleDTO schild = new ComponentStyleDTO();
                schild.setAttribute(key);
                schild.setValue((String) child.get(key));
                childs.add(schild);
            }
            return childs;
        }else{
            return value;
        }

    }

}
```

And here's how I'm using this:

```
    HashMap<String, Object> hmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hmap.put(attr.getKey(), attr.getValue());
    ComponentStyleDTO componentDTO = componentStyleMapper.hashMapToComponentStyleDTO(hmap);
```

But it's returning me empty in attribute and value. Any idea of what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have getters/setters( or lombok or so) on DTO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve. If your mapping is more complex maybe the best way is indeed to go with the approach in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54601058/1115491.

That a side, the reason why it is not working for you is that you have not defined the source for your mapping. In the example you linked there is a POJO as source parameter and the source is a map in that POJO. In order to make it work your mapper needs to look like:

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, componentModel = "spring", uses = ComponentStyleMapperUtil.class)
public interface ComponentStyleMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "attribute", source = "hashMap", qualifiedBy = ComponentStyleMapperUtil.Attribute.class)
    @Mapping(target = "value", source = "hashMap", qualifiedBy = ComponentStyleMapperUtil.Value.class)
    ComponentStyleDTO hashMapToComponentStyleDTO(HashMap<String, Object> hashMap);
}
```

**NB**: When using the non default `componentModel` you should not use the `Mappers` factory for getting an instance of the mapper. If you do that you will get an NPE when working with other mappers.

Comment: Thank you. I did use another approach, but thank ou for replying a fix for this!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO The best way is the simpliest way:

```
default ComponentStyleDTO hashMapToComponentStyleDTO(HashMap<String, Object> hashMap){
    ComponentStyleDTO result = new ComponentStyleDTO();
    result.setAtribute1(hashMap.get("atribute1"));
    result.setAtribute2(hashMap.get("atribute2"));
    result.setAtribute3(hashMap.get("atribute3"));
    ...
    return result;
}
```

or

```
default List<ComponentStyleDTO> hashMapToComponentStyleDTO(HashMap<String, Object> hashMap){
    return hashMap.entrySet()
                  .stream()
                  .map(e -> new ComponentStyleDTO(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this wouldn't work in my example since the value can be another hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference. As of Mapstruct 1.5 I think this usecase is supported out of the box. See [mapstruct release note](https://mapstruct.org/news/2021-07-18-mapstruct-1_5_0_Beta1-is-out/#mapping-from-map-to-bean)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).